# Origin of Bubbles' monkey noise

Tags: plot-explanation, character, trailer-park-boys

If you've ever watched [Trailer Park Boys](http://earnthis.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/130704b-trailer-park-boys.jpg) you might have noticed Bubbles makes this strange monkey noise whenever he's excited.

In the episode [Propane, Propane](http://trailerpark.wikia.com/wiki/Propane,_Propane_(Episode)) Ricky refers to it specifically when Bubbles gets some bad news :

> "Come on Bubbles, make those monkey noises... like you do when you're happy"

We only hear Bubbles make the noise from season 2 onwards. I'm just wondering if there is any in-universe explanation for that noise?